# Crossfading DIVs + stopping animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Would it be possible to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asTBL/

```
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
    })
}, 2500)
})
```

But with the DIVs crossfading directly into each other rather than first fading to white and then fading from white?

Also, would it be possible to stop the animation on hover (and resume it when not hovering)?

I searched for several solutions but couldn't find a way to do it (I'm a noob with javascript). CSS solutions didn't match my needs because they wouldn't work correctly with DIVs having links inside it...

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible... what have you tried ?

Comment: You have to provide a concrete sample in question itself, not just linking to an old question

Comment: @Danko: I tried CSS solutions but they wouldn't work exactly as I needed them to, so I resorted to search for javascript solutions (which I can't write) and found this one.

A. Wolff, added, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your divs fade at the same time you will need to add a bit of styling (to make the quotes sit on top of each other) and run the fades simultaneously.  Then you will need to clear the timeout on hover to pause the animation:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div.quote'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    var fadeInterval = setFadeInterval(); // starts the fader

    $els.hover(function () {
        clearInterval(fadeInterval); // stops the fader on mouseover
    },

    function () {
        fadeInterval = setFadeInterval(); // restarts the fader on mouseout
    });

    function setFadeInterval() {
        return setInterval(function () {
            $els.eq(i).fadeOut(); // run the faders at the same time
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
        }, 2500);
    }
});
```

```css
/* make the faders sit on top of each other */
#quote-holder {
    position:relative;
}
#quote-holder > .quote {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote-holder">
    <div id="quote1" class="quote"> <span class="quote">I am a quote</span>
 <span class="author">Author Name</span>

    </div>
    <div id="quote2" class="quote">I am another quote</div>
    <div id="quote3" class="quote">I am yet another quote</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woo, that seems to work perfectly! I'll try it in my environment (DIVs will contain images with anchor) and let you know! Thanks very much!

Comment: You will need to give the `quote-holder` a width and height to match the dimensions of your largest image as the quotes won't take up any space as they are positioned absolutely

Comment: You have a lot of js errors (press f12 in your browser and look at the console tab) - the main one being you haven't included the jQuery library

Comment: I noticed you are also using mootools so you may want to look at [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools)

Comment: I now added jquery above everything else but still nothing. Now I remember why I was looking for CSS solutions first lol, me and JS hate each other... Sorry for bothering you beyond the scope of the questions but I can't get it to work :( Also, I would need the jquery library only in this page, do you advice to include it in the whole template of the site anyway, or is there a way to include it in a PHP file only (the one that controls the calendar cells)?

Comment: I would include it only on that page and then use the `noConflict()` option for that page or use a pure css3 fade slider: http://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk (although this one doesn't have a pause on hover option) but if you google I bet there is probably one out there

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, since it is and you even went beyond to try to help me. I just couldn't get it to work on my site for some reason but I'll keep trying. Can't use CSS because I need an individual link on each div and that doesn't work with CSS unfortunately :( Thank you very much for you help, much appeciated.

Comment: Try opening a new question about the mootools and jquery.  Sorry I couldn't help any more as my work has a site policy and I used up my quota time so couldn't look at your site anymore!  Or you could always try using a mootools image slider: http://mootools.net/forge/p/pictureslider

Comment: I managed to get it to work on the live site! Now we only need to fix that little issue!

Comment: I made it a jsfiddle for easier viewing: http://jsfiddle.net/bdg7mfzb/3/
Thank you very much!

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bdg7mfzb/4/ - if it doen't answer your you should open a new question

Comment: OMG! You're the fn man. It works perfectly. Can I donate to you or something? This is top notch. It looks so beautiful on my live site in each and every instance multiple events occur. Amazing.

Comment: Nice one, glad I could help :)

Comment: Just noticed it doesn't fade well in IE, but then again, who cares about IE LOL. I really appreciated your help! I've been heavily customizing this calendar component on all PHP, HTML and CSS aspects, but I couldn't write JS if my life depended on it xD Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asTBL/)

```
jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
var timer = setInterval(animation, 2500)
function animation(){
     $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
    })
}
$('#content').hover(function (){
clearInterval(timer);  
  },function (){
  setInterval(animation,2500);
})
```

})

I restructure your code and create a animation function to achieve.